# What if your question is closed for duplicate but you don't understand a thing about the given solution?

Tags: discussion, voting, closed-questions

Is there a way in stackexchange network to complain about closing questions and other moderating behaviour?

I'm getting afraid to ask questions - weird because in the end it is a Q&A network: that relies on questions being asked and solved. I've often seen questions being marked as "duplicate" where I think: hey I did not understand the original answer, so why SHOULDN'T I reask the question. - To maybe get a second way of wording the solution (wording matters a lot).

Or when I see very interesting questions being "closed" because of vague. Did not anyone who voted to close consider that maybe the asker is less experienced? And it is vague **because** the asker does not have enough capability to phrase the question in good manner? Closing questions for vague is the biggest arrogance in that case that can happen: and it equivalent to saying "I don't wish to teach you, you're dumb and should stay dumb".

Another point is that currently I'm out of time to actually program, and I consider actually writing code a waste of time. I just do what I love, solve problems and use the abstract thinking skills of translating a problem.
However this means I can't put forth any "code" and I'm in the fear of questions being closed for doing too little work; even if I don't ask for code and I don't WANT code. I just want to understand algorithms. Language agnostic.

Or actually this post in itself: I see a lot of "similar questions" yet none have a satisfying solution: what am I supposed to do that? As I think the question I ask has a slightly different way than the other questions. (IE: most suggestion talk about single moderating behaviour, while I consider not a problem with a specific person).

---

A more direct question for those who want to answer something:
What if your question is closed for duplicate but you don't understand a thing about the given solution?

An example (though not on stackoverflow, it shares similarity in rulings right?) - [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78975/newtonian-gravity-equation-in-a-2-dimensional-world) -. The duplicate question is asking indeed the same topic - but handled it from a different perspective, I knew the answer and was only asking for verification. However had I not known the answer I wouldn't have understood the duplicates.

Comment: I think this will go better for you if you point out the specific posts that you're having trouble with.

Comment: "How to complain about moderation?" You pretty much just have, and already have a mod's attention..

Comment: @James it is not about the MODERATORS, it is about the self moderating of users.

Comment: A) you just have, B) the Q&A network relies on **good** questions being asked and interesting answers being given. If the questions are largely terrible, the network becomes less attractive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: well that's a bit the problem, it is a feeling I have over the whole stackexchange family, seeing a problem here, seeing a problem there. It has lead to me being afraid to ask things now.

Comment: Ironically, this question is too vague to be answerable.  Is there some way you can change it from a wandering generality into something more concrete and specific?

Comment: "What if your question is closed for duplicate but you don't understand a thing about the given solution?" Read the duplicate(s), ask something more specific not a duplicate, read tutorials on the subject, come back and ask specific questions with no answers already available (ie no dupes)

Comment: If you're interested in asking about algorithms _sans_ code, you should join [Programmers.SE] and/or [cs.se]. That said, everything above the fold here just seems to be a rant (the gist of which we've heard many times before, let me add). What kind of response are you looking for here? What kind of positive result can you imagine (for yourself or the site) from your posting of this question?

Answer (score 9):

> Why SHOULDN'T I reask the question

Because that scatters answers to the same question all over the place - this is not good. If a user has a question, (s)he should simply be able to visit one discussion and find all applicable answers there.

If you didn't understand the answer to another question, one of these would be preferred:

- Comment on the answer to ask for clarification on a specific aspect (I say "a specific aspect", as a vague request to clarify the answer is likely to be ignored or be followed by a "Can you be more specific?" comment)
- Put a bounty on the question asking for a more understandable answer

Somewhat related post - [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

And it's 10x worse is if you find yourself in this scenario, but you don't actually link to the other question - in this case, users may go to the trouble of writing up a very similar answer to the one in the duplicate question from stratch, which is essentially just wasting their time, since you won't understand it.

> Or when I see very interesting questions being "closed" because of vague

Often the difference between me voting to close a question that's description is completely incomprehensible simply comes down to whether or not there's an proper example to explain it. If there is, I can usually figure out what OP meant and attempt to modify the explanation appropriately.

I basically always ask for an example if one isn't provided, but after a while I give up on waiting and (either leave or) simply vote to close the question. We can't wait forever for enough information to be able to answer the question.

Remember that questions can always be reopened.

> Another point is that currently I'm out of time to actually program, and I consider actually writing code a waste of time.

We don't want to necessarily see code, but at least give *some* evidence that you actually tried to solve the problem yourself. To be honest, I'd often prefer *not* to see code. But at least give some high-level description of an ideas you've had.<sup>[1]</sup>

Remember that we're not getting paid to help you. And, because of this, we'd at least like some evidence that you tried to solve the problem yourself. If you don't understand *why* we want this, just think of this as some sort of payment - hardly a lot to ask for.

[1]: I'm (probably) mainly talking about algorithm questions here. For, for example, a "How do I do this simple thing in Java?" question, I expect to see actual code.

> Random additional notes

If you haven't already, I suggest you work your way through [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in-depth.

I'd like to specifically point out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), that points you to http://SSCCE.org, which gives advice for constructing a proper example of a problem, and [the question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the main applicable points here being:

> - Have you done some research before asking the question? <sup>1</sup>
> - Have you explained what you've already tried to solve your problem?
>
> <sup>1</sup> If you went from "something's not working" to "asking a question" in less than 10 minutes, you probably haven't done enough research. This should include things like normal web searches (e.g. for an error message you're receiving), checking the documentation, debugging (particularly for exceptions) and searching on Stack Overflow itself for similar questions.

I can't highlight this enough - **use the comments**.

More often than not, question askers fall into one of two categories:

- Ask and run - user asks a question and isn't seen for at least a few hours.
- Selective responder - user does respond to comments, but only one or two here and there.

Stick around for **at least** an hour after asking a question to respond to any comments.

Try to respond to **all** comments that ask something.

If someone mentions that your question is a duplicate of another question and you disagree, point out to the user concrete reasons why the two are not the same. If you already found this question prior to asking yours, it could be wise to include a link to it in your question, mentioning the difference - this reduces the chance of it being closed as a duplicate of that question, and, at the same time, also shows some research attempt from your side.

If someone asks for clarification, do you best to clarify, expand, give examples, etc.

Two random resources:

- [Help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Now these are not exactly the ... friendliest links to be pointed to, but do give them an objective read through and, after you've written your question, before posting it, read through it with those posts in mind, and ask yourself - can **anyone** consider your post to classify as **any** of the things mentioned in those posts? If so, you should probably put some more work into your question.

Answer (score 6):

> What if your question is closed for duplicate but you don't understand a thing about the given solution?

In that case, consider writing a new question which explicitly mentions the question marked as a duplicate, and very specific reasons why you don't fully understand the answer in the original (being as detailed as possible).

Ideally, you would do some external research, do your best to understand the answer, and include in your question any points of confusion/questions you have. (As a good rule of thumb, the more effort you show, the better things will go)

If you do so, you're essentially asking something new, and your question, by definition, cannot be a duplicate.

Comment: I see that you've brought answers into this equation.  Keep in mind that answers have nothing to do with question duplication.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1. Ask the question again (perhaps in a more specific way), and explain in the body of your question why your new question doesn't duplicate the original question, or
2. Post a bounty on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just focus on two aspects of your rather broad question here:

- Should I re-ask a question if I don't understand the answer?

That depends; are you lacking basics to understand the answer? Can the problem be broken down further and you can understand it on your own given some time and research? Then don't ask the same question again.

Is there something specific about the answer which needs clarification and you cannot figure it out on your own; sure, a new question is fine.

- What if an interesting question is closed because it is too vague?

Improve the question without changing its intent. It will automatically be queued in the reopen queue and reopened if the improved question fits the SE format.